# Simulate mouse click for side buttons

Tags: c#, c++, mouse

I am aware of how to use mouse_event to simulate a mouse click for the left or right buttons. What I would like to know is if this function or another in C#/C++ allows you to simulate the mouse4 or mouse5 buttons that gaming mice have?

Comment: I think it depends on the mouse.. all the mice like this I have used set their buttons to act as if they are other keyboard controls (etc.) I don't think you'll find the background code for this on a public domain.. (unless mice developers have an sdk)

Comment: Windows Forms? WPF? Silverlight? etc.?

Comment: I am using Windows forms, but the simulation I need is not passing extra parameters to my own functions. It is to be sent to external applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mouse4` and `mouse5` in windows are named `xbutton1` and `xbutton2`

You can use these:

```
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_XDOWN, NULL, NULL, XBUTTON1, NULL);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_XDOWN, NULL, NULL, XBUTTON2, NULL);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_XUP, NULL, NULL, XBUTTON1, NULL);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_XUP, NULL, NULL, XBUTTON2, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `RAWINPUT` structure and send it using the `WM_INPUT` windows message to the window.

[WM_INPUT reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[RAWINPUT reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645562%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[RAWINPUT P/Invoke reference](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/RAWINPUT.html)

Speifically, you will need to create a `RAWMOUSE` struct for use inside the `RAWINPUT`. the `RAWMOUSE`'s `usButtonFlags` field can contain info regarding the 4th and 5th mouse buttons.

[RAWMOUSE reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645578%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[RAWMOUSE P/Invoke reference](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/RAWINPUTMOUSE.html)
[RAWMOUSEBUTTONS Enumeration P/Invoke reference](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/RawMouseButtons.html)

The exact implementation you will need to use depends on the target application and platform. You may need to register the window for raw input before it will receive any `WM_INPUT` messages.